# Using conditionals in GitLab CI with user intervention

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, ansible-template

Is that possible to add conditionals that executes if or else block based on a user input in GitLab CI yml?

In the event the user input is a YES then it must trigger a template(ansible tower template) to restart specific service (tower-cli job launch --job-template)

Should I use`rules:if` with `when` for such a conditional.Could someone put an insight on such a format.I am a first time user in Gitlab and have some experience in Jenkins.

Comment: Where would this user input come from? Is it an edit to `.gitlab-ci.yml`? A variable provided to a manual job? And environment variable that changes between pipelines?

Comment: It`s an input to a manual job. Once input is provided then an ansible role should execute with a task to start only those services passed as an input by the user. The user input can be one or multiple in number.

Answer (score 2):

The [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) section (and also [`only` and `except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)) are evaluated when the pipeline is first created, but before the first job starts running because it controls which jobs will be in a pipeline or not, so you can't use variables/conditionals that come from another job or manual task variables.

An alternative is to use a normal [bash conditional](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) in your script section and simply `exit 0;` when the job shouldn't run.

```yaml
...
Job:
  stage: my_stage
  when: manual
  script:
    - if [ $MY_USER_INPUT_VARIABLE == "don't run the job" ] then exit 0; fi
    - ./run_job.sh
```

These are just simple examples, but you check the variable for whatever it is you need it to do (or use multiple conditionals if using multiple variables) and if the job shouldn't run, execute `exit 0;` which will stop the job from processing, but will not mark it as *failed*. Otherwise, we run whatever we need this job to do.